# Base64 Decryption with given encryption algorithm (DES base64, secretKey, Cipher)

Tags: java, encryption, base64

When I encrypt the password **!QAZxdr5** by the code below:

```
public static String encryptPassword(String msg) {
    try {
        KeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(msg.getBytes());
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(keySpec);
        Cipher ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        //Encode the string into bytes using utf-8
        byte[] utf8 = msg.getBytes("UTF8");
        //Encrypt
        byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);
        //Encode bytes to base64 to get a string
        return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(enc));
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I got the output: **QQiu2a4NT9YfDAtmHjbk1A==**

Now I try to create the decryption for this:

```
public static String decrypt(String msg) {
    try {
        KeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(msg.getBytes());
        SecretKey key = 
        SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(keySpec);
        Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
        decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        // Decode base64 to get bytes
        byte[] dec = Base64.getDecoder().decode(msg.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        //Decrypt
        byte[] utf8 = decipher.doFinal(dec);
        //Decode using utf-8
        return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, it doesn't work properly as it returned null :(. Can you please help to check where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, Base64 encoding of `!QAZxdr5` is `IVFBWnhkcjU=`, however, your code uses a key to encode extra AFAI understand, that's why you get `QQiu2a4NT9YfDAtmHjbk1A==`. So, `decrypt()` method needs to know also the key generated already, nonetheless, yours wouldn't.

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Base64;


class EncryptDecryptTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        String key = "it's our key ~~~where is my +1 karma ??~~~ - soner";



        String ciphertext = encrypt(key, "!QAZxdr5");

        String decrypted = decrypt(key, ciphertext.trim());
        String encrypted = encrypt(key, decrypted.trim());

        if (ciphertext.contentEquals(encrypted.trim())) {
            System.out.println("decrypted!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("wrong key!");
        }
    }

    public static String encrypt(String key, String data)
            throws GeneralSecurityException {
        DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);
        byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(dataBytes));
    }

    public static String decrypt(String key, String data)
            throws GeneralSecurityException {
        byte[] dataBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(data);
        DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] dataBytesDecrypted = (cipher.doFinal(dataBytes));
        return new String(dataBytesDecrypted);
    }
}
```

---

As a side note,

The fact that `return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(enc));` uses `toString()` method of *array*
should be `return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(enc);` in order to get expected encoded datum.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But the point is that I found the encrypt in the source code of an application, now I'm trying to create only the decryption for that, it makes no sense to change the encryption. The string "!QAZxdr5" is to test if the decryption work properly or not to decrypt the encrypted string "QQiu2a4NT9YfDAtmHjbk1A=="

Comment: I fully understand your explanation. Very much appreciated. However, the problem is that the first encryption use the input string for generating the key KeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(msg.getBytes());. Now I wonder if is there any way to create a decryption for that. We don't change the first encryption, just concentrate on how to make the decryption accordingly. To be quite honest your solution is work very well but it doesn't solve my problem. Since I have the encrypted string of "!QAZxdr5" is "QQiu2a4NT9YfDAtmHjbk1A==", so what is the orginal string of "HCI+xqaqBU8LIO0A7JErwQ=="?

Comment: @ThienNguyen `String key = "!QAZxdr5";` and `String ciphertext = encrypt(key, "!QAZxdr5");` , then you get your intent! I think it is really tommyrot and vulnerable.

Comment: The key = "!QAZxdr5" will only work if the original string is "!QAZxdr5". I obviously cannot use the key for decrypting "HCI+xqaqBU8LIO0A7JErwQ==" :( because I don't know what is its original string which I have to figure out by decryption.

Answer (score 0):

In DES encryption, it uses the same key to encrypt and decrypt a message.
So for both operations you need to have the same key.

In your case, you have used the same string as the key and as the password.

```
public static String encryptPassword(String msg) {
    try {
        KeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(msg.getBytes());
```

In above code segment when creating new DESKeySpec object, you need to pass the key as well.

```
public static String decrypt(String msg) {
    try {
        KeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(msg.getBytes());
```

Even in above decypt method you have to pass the same key you have used in encrypt method.
But in this you have given the encoded string to generate the key.
That is where you have gone wrong.

So i suggest you to change the methods parameters by adding one more parameter as key and then pass the same value for key in both methods.

```
  public static String encryptPassword(String msg, String keySp) {
        try {
            KeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(keySp.getBytes());
            }

    public static String decrypt(String msg, String keySp) {
            try {
                KeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(keySp.getBytes());
                }
```

I have included only the lines that needed to be changed.

You can call those methods by,

```
String key = "!QAZxdr5";
String password = "!QAZxdr5";
String encriptedPassword = encryptPassword(password, key);
System.out.println(decrypt(encriptedPassword, key));
```